# Sequential Lookup of specific string across 3 tables for multiple records and display by latest entry

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have 3 tables wherein I need to search for a specific string '%sell back%' in sequential order and get the **latest** entry depending on where I find it first further details are listed below
Table#3, the 3 tables are as follows:

Table#1: Customer

```
|---------------|---------------|
|  CustomerID   | CustomerName  |
|---------------|---------------|
|    1234       | Johnathan     |
|---------------|---------------|
```

Table#2: Problem

```
|---------------|---------------|----------------------|---------------|
|  ProblemID    | CustomerID    | ProblemDescription   | DateReported  |
|---------------|---------------|----------------------|---------------|
|    3203494    | 1234          | Needs Appointment    | 2019-08-01    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    3178766    | 1234          | Sell Back Customer   | 2019-08-12    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    3178765    | 1234          |                      | 2019-08-12    |
|---------------|---------------|----------------------|---------------|
```

Table#3: Problem Event

```
|---------------|---------------|----------------------|---------------|
|ProblemEventID | ProblemID     | EventReason          | EventDate     |
|---------------|---------------|----------------------|---------------|
|    1926144    | 3178766       | Reported             | 2019-08-12    | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    2022750    | 3178766       | sell back            | 2019-08-13    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    2022751    | 3178766       | Accepted as sell back| 2019-08-26    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    2022899    | 3178766       | Finalized            | 2019-08-31    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    1926200    | 3178765       | Reported             | 2019-09-15    | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    2022626    | 3178765       | sell back            | 2019-09-20    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    2024500    | 3178765       | Accepted as sell back| 2019-09-30    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    2024501    | 3178765       | Finalized            | 2019-10-05    |
|---------------|---------------|----------------------|---------------|
```

The result that I am looking for should be extracted following the sequence of steps listed below:

**Step#1**

Search for '%sell back%' string in ProblemDescription column of Problem Table if exists then choose the corresponding ProblemID with latest DateReported and proceed to Step#2

**Step #2**

Search for the corresponding problem ID (selected in Step#1) in Problem Event table and check if '%sell back%' string exists in EventReason column of the Problem Event table, and select the latest entry
and display as follows

```
|---------------|---------------|------------|-----------------------|-----------------------|------------|
|  CustomerID   | CustomerName  | ProblemId  | ProblemDescription    |      EventReason      | EventDate  |
|---------------|---------------|------------|-----------------------|-----------------------|------------|
|    1234       | Johnathan     | 3178766    | Sell Back Customer    | Accepted as sell back | 2019-08-26 |
|---------------|---------------|------------|-----------------------|-----------------------|------------|
```

If for Step#2 no string '%sell back%' is found in Problem Event table's EventReason column then shall display the latest row for corresponding ProblemID from Problem Event table

**Alternate Sequence:**

If Step#1 search for '%sell back%' string does not yield any results i.e. ProblemDescription column contains no '%sell back%' string then search for the same string '%sell back%' directly in 
Problem Event table and select the latest entry and display the results as follows:

```
|---------------|---------------|------------|-----------------------|-----------------------|------------|
|  CustomerID   | CustomerName  | ProblemId  | ProblemDescription    |      EventReason      | EventDate  |
|---------------|---------------|------------|-----------------------|-----------------------|------------|
|    1234       | Johnathan     | 3178765    |                       | Accepted as sell back | 2019-10-05 |
|---------------|---------------|------------|-----------------------|-----------------------|------------|
```

I am looking to fetch the results for multiple customer records ~ 10K records.

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: How is this different from your previous question?

Comment: @SMor in this question I am looking to scan the problem table first and look for the '%sell back%' tag and then find the latest '%sell back%' entry in the problem event table. Whereas in the previous question I was just looking for '%sell back%' tag inside of the problem event table.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below solution using `row_number`. here is the [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fd135/28).

```
select 
    subq.customerID,
    customerName,
    problemID,
    problemDescription,
    eventReason,
    eventDate
from
(
  select 
    customerID,      
    p.problemID,
    problemDescription,
    eventReason,
    eventDate,
    count(*) over (partition by p.problemID) as cnt,
    row_number() over (partition by p.problemID order by DateReported desc) as pbrn,
    row_number() over (partition by pe.problemID order by eventDate desc) as pern
  from problem p
  join problemEvent pe
  on p.problemID = pe.problemID
  where (problemDescription like '%sell back%'
  and eventReason like '%sell back%') 
  or eventReason like '%sell back%'
) subq
join customer c
on subq.customerID = c.customerID
where (cnt = 1
and pbrn = 1)
or pern = 1
```

Output:

```
*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*
| customerID    customerName    problemID   problemDescription  eventReason             eventDate |
*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*
|   1234         Johnathan       3178766    Sell Back Customer  Accepted as sell back  2019-08-26 |
*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*
```

Comment: Hi @zealous thanks for the help but this query is not finding those rows in the Problem table where the PorblemDescription is empty but there is '%sell back%' tag present for the corresponding problemid in the problem event table.